# Python: combine boolean columns in Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data

```
attr1_A    attr1_B    attr1_C    attr1_D    attr2_A    attr2_B   attr2_C
      1          0          0          1          1          0         0
      0          1          1          0          0          0         1
      0          0          0          0          0          1         0
      1          1          1          0          1          1         0
```

I want to retain `attr1_A`, `attr1_B` and combine `attr1_C` and `attr1_D` into `attr1_others`. As long as `attr1_C` and/or `attr1_D` is 1, then `attr1_others` will be 1. Similarly, I want to keep `attr2_A` but combine the remaining `attr2_*` into `attr2_others`. Like this:

```
attr1_A    attr1_B    attr1_others    attr2_A    attr2_others
      1          0          1               1               0     
      0          1          1               0               1  
      0          0          0               0               1 
      1          1          1               1               1
```

In other words, for any group of `attr`, I want to retain a few known columns but combine the remaining (which I don't know how many remaining `attr` of the same group.

I am thinking of doing each group separately: processing all `attr1_*`, and then `attr2_*` because there are a limited number of groups in my dataset, but many attr under each group.

What I can think right now is to retrieve the `others` columns like:

```
# for group 1
df[x for x in df.columns if "A" not in x and "B" not in x and "attr1_" in x]

# for group 2
df[x for x in df.columns if "A" not in x and "attr2_" in x]
```

And to combine, I am thinking of using `any` function, but I can't come up with the syntax. Could you help?

**Updated attempt**:

I tried this

```
# for group 1
df['attr1_others'] = df[df[[x for x in list(df.columns) 
                            if "attr1_" in x
                            and "A" not in x 
                            and "B" not in x]].any(axis = 'column')]
```

but got the below error:

> ValueError: No axis named column for object type `<`class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom list to select columns, and then `.any()` with `axis=1` parameter. To convert to interger, use `.astype(int)`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'attr1_A': [1, 0, 0, 1],
        'attr1_B': [0, 1, 0, 1],
        'attr1_C': [0, 1, 0, 1],
        'attr1_D': [1, 0, 0, 0],
        'attr2_A': [1, 0, 0, 1],
        'attr2_B': [0, 0, 1, 1],
        'attr2_C': [0, 1, 0, 0]})

cols = [col for col in df.columns.values if col.startswith('attr1') and col.split('_')[1] not in ('A', 'B')]
df['attr1_others'] = df[cols].any(axis=1).astype(int)
df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

cols = [col for col in df.columns.values if col.startswith('attr2') and col.split('_')[1] not in ('A', )]
df['attr2_others'] = df[cols].any(axis=1).astype(int)
df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   attr1_A  attr1_B  attr2_A  attr1_others  attr2_others
0        1        0        1             1             0
1        0        1        0             1             1
2        0        0        0             0             1
3        1        1        1             1             1
```

Answer (score 2):

Dataframes have the great ability to manipulate data in place, without having to write complex python logic.

To create your `attr1_others` and `attr2_others` columns, you can combine the columns with `or` conditions using this:

```
df['attr1_others'] = df['attr1_C'] | df['attr1_D']
df['attr2_others'] = df['attr2_B'] | df['attr2_C']
```

If instead, you wanted an `and` condition, you could use:

```
df['attr1_others'] = df['attr1_C'] & df['attr1_D']
df['attr2_others'] = df['attr2_B'] & df['attr2_C']
```

You can then delete the lingering original values using `del`:

```
del df['attr1_C']
del df['attr1_D']
del df['attr2_B']
del df['attr2_C']
```

Comment: Hi @StevenMoseley, there are many `attr1_*` to be combined, not just `C` and `D`. Is there a way to combine all `attr1_*` that are not `A` and `B` ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of kept-columns. Drop those kept-columns out and assign left-over columns to new dataframe `df1`. Groupby `df1` by the splitted column names; call `any` on axis=1; `add_suffix` '_others' and assign result to `df2`. Finally, join and sort_index

```
keep_cols = ['attr1_A', 'attr1_B', 'attr2_A']
df1 = df.drop(keep_cols,1)
df2 = (df1.groupby(df1.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1)
          .any(1).add_suffix('_others').astype(int))

Out[512]:
   attr1_others  attr2_others
0             1             0
1             1             1
2             0             1
3             1             1

df_final = df[keep_cols].join(df2).sort_index(1)

Out[514]:
   attr1_A  attr1_B  attr1_others  attr2_A  attr2_others
0        1        0             1        1             0
1        0        1             1        0             1
2        0        0             0        0             1
3        1        1             1        1             1
```